# Cakephp how to get callback validation error message from model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get validation error message from model and display this in json output.
Is there a way we can catch this callback in variables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can access the validation messages in the controller:

```
$errors = $this->Model->validationErrors;
```

then you can use it for whatever you like

Comment: Why this happen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929323/how-i-can-display-validation-error-message-in-webservice?noredirect=1#comment35001435_22929323