# How i can display validation error message in webservice

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I get validation error message in

```
$this->User->validationErrors;
```

But problem is when i assign like

```
DebugBreak();   //For debug my script
$response['type']='error';
$error = $this->User->validationErrors;
```

$response['message'] contains empty array. why this happen? help me.

Comment: why don't you use json_encode?

Comment: I used json_encode like json_encode($this->User->validationErrors) but get empty array

Comment: json encoding has absolutely nothing to do with this -.-

Comment: @RápliAndrás What you mean?

Comment: `array()` to `[]`, okay, but it still stays empty. That was the problem, wasn't it? By the way you can set the response message in your model's `$validate` array http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove DebugBreak from my script then it work perfect like this

```
$response['type']='error';
$error = $this->User->validationErrors;
```